# How to make well-encapsulated classes while using unordered_set/map in c++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, encapsulation, unordered-map, unordered-set

I was looking at some tutorials on how to make an unordered_set for a class/struct. I found this easy-to-understand code (as a Java developer) which does the trick:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int val;
  
    bool operator==(const Node& n) const{
        return (this->val == n.val);
    }
};

class HashFunction{
    public:
        size_t operator()(const Node& n) const{
            return n.val;
        }
};

int main(){
    Node n1 = { 1 }, n2 = { 2 },
         n3 = { 3 }, n4 = { 4 };

    unordered_set<Node, HashFunction> us;
    us.insert(n1);
    us.insert(n2);
    us.insert(n3);
    us.insert(n4);
    
    for (auto node : us){
        cout << node.val << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was wondering if we can make the `struct Node` a class, make the `int val` a private field and add `unordered_set<Node, HashFunction> neighbours` as a field to the `Node` class.

If not, what is a good practice to keep classes/structs well-encapsulated and have sets/maps fields for classes?

Comment: Note that `Node` in C++ means the actual object, not a pointer as it does in Java.  A "neighbors" collection needs a many-to-many relationship which can only be implemented with pointers.

Comment: Struct is just a class with the default being public for all members. If you made val private, then class Hash couldn't return it.

Comment: @BenVoigt thank you for the comment, do you mean that the set "neighbours" should have a Node* as a template?

Comment: @sucksatnetworking thank you for the comment. I will try to make the "Node" a class now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few questions here, so I'll try to answer them in order:

> can make the `struct Node` a class

Yes, `struct` and `class` only differ in their default permissions (in `struct` things are `public` unless stated otherwise, in `class` they are `private`)
So this is identical code to what you wrote:

```
class Node{
public:
    int val;
  
    bool operator==(const Node& n) const{
        return (this->val == n.val);
    }
};
```

> make the `int val` a private field and add `unordered_set<Node, HashFunction> neighbours` as a field to the `Node` class

Yes, you can. The easiest way I can think of to make that transition from the code that you wrote is to make `HashFunction` be a sub-class of `Node`.
For example:

```
class Node {
    class HashFunction {
        public:
            size_t operator()(const Node& n) const{
                return n.val;
            }
    };

public:
    Node(int _val) : val(_val) {}

    bool operator==(const Node& n) const{
        return (this->val == n.val);
    }

    // More methods here

private:
    int val;
    unordered_set<Node, HashFunction> neighbours;
};
```

> If not, what is a good practice to keep classes/structs well-encapsulated and have sets/maps fields for classes?

I guess that is somewhat of a mute question in this case - but the general answer is to expose only the minimum required interface. For example, right now `HushFunction` is aware of the internal content of `Node`. in order to increase encapsulation we could have added a `hush` method to `Node` and have `HushFunction` invoke that method. This way if the content of `Node` changes, nothing outside of `Node` needs to be aware of it.